Can I use Mapbox GL JS to find the nearest point on a road to a given coordinate?
I am utilising Mapbox in my application and it would be useful to identify the nearest point that is on a road to any given coordinate.
It looks like Google has this capability but doesn't seem as if Mapbox's reverse geocoder would help out of the box.
Is there another way that Mapboxs' functionality could be utilised to achieve the same?
Mapboxs' AI assistant has suggested the Map Matching API, but this looks to 'snap' a drawing of a route to the road network rather than return any point on the road network...

The recommended way to achieve this is using the Directions API. The start point of the route will be the nearest point on the road network, to your remote coordinate.
